# What indoor plants or groups of plants are significant consumers of CO2?

Tags: botany

I am experimenting with the goal to reduce CO2 ppm in a 4200 sqr ft (12 rooms) dwelling by either distributing more plants through the space, or using a hydroponic garden's air as a source in the dwelling for a CO2 filtering system.
Using plants that are high consumers of CO2 will provide ppm data measurements to influence which solution I take.
What plants or groups of plants should I consider?

Thank You!

Greg Messer

Comment: the type of plant might be less important than the growing conditions.

Comment: I would imagine there are other criteria that are equally as important as just CO2 consumption such how easy they are to grow and maintain and how much space they take up. And cost. I just used snake plants. Humans have pretty exhaustively gone through the list of what plants are suitable as houseplants.

Comment: What type of ventilation system is used in this dwelling? Is the CO2 mostly coming from the occupants, or are there combustion sources too?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly one of the extremely fast growing aquatic plants such as [Azolla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azolla) might be an option. Plants in this genus are sometimes mentioned as carbon dioxide remediation mechanisms due to their extremely fast doubling times.

Anything else that shows high productivity (rate of carbon fixation/photosynthesis) might be an option. You would obviously need to tailor the environment to suit that high growth rate, as suggested by commenters.

I was surprised to [read just now](https://phys.org/news/2013-07-air-hidden-indoor.html) that plants apparently are (can be!) actually effective at indoor CO2 remediation. I had not thought that they were terribly effective. Though some of this is due to other associated organisms e.g. bacteria in potting soil.